# transcation getting rolled back

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I want to insert a case and send error using addError() method in salesforce in Before update trigger.But using addError method case getting rolled back.
In Before update

if(condition)
Insert a case
acc.addError()`enter code here`
}
}

Answer (score 0):

That's how it works. You can't have transaction succeed (save successfully) and throw exception at same time.
If you want to save the case but show something to user consider setting some field on it, sending email, making a Task user has to complete, Chatter post maybe.
Or make custom UI piece (lightning web component?) and there you could for example abuse record-edit-form's onsuccess handler to display red toast if you want. That'll be just UI thing though, Data Loader and integrations won't care.

Comment: Is there any workaround , my requirement is create a case on before update Account in salesforce and send error to external system using platform event

Comment: Just don't use addError for this? Raise the platform event, you can give it a meaning of error because you control the payload... But don't block the save, don't create real SF exception